# create custom log file for every time controller action is run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, logfiles

**I would like to create a log file for every time I run true controller#action**
to better debug a complex controller action in my application.

My controller:

```
class GameController < extends ApplicationController


def game
   sm_logger.info("Creating new game with id: #{params[:id}")    
end
```

Model custom logger function:

```
def sm_logger
  @@sm_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/sm.log")
end
```

What would be a good approach to have a new log file created every time this is run? 
Something like ( where the numbers are the params[:id] :

```
* 01/01/2012_1_sm.log
* 01/01/2012_2_sm.log
* 01/01/2012_3_sm.log
```

Anyone could point me in the right direction? thx!